# Using GROUP BY clause to replace dissimilar rows with single value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do something like (psuedo - of course):

```
SELECT 
  city,
  CASE WHEN COUNT( [group] ) > 1 THEN 'Multiple' ELSE [group] END  AS Type 
FROM 
  offices
GROUP BY
  city
```

Where offices contains rows like:

```
ID |   group   |  city
----------------------
1  |    'A'    | 'Houston'
2  |    'B'    | 'Houston'
3  |    'C'    | 'Houston'
4  |    'S'    | 'Boston'
5  |    'R'    | 'Detroit'
```

and result would look something like:

```
   city   | group
--------------------
 'Houston'| 'Multiple'
 'Boston' |   'S'
 'Detroit'|   'R'
```

I know you can do:

```
SELECT 
  City,
  CASE WHEN COUNT([group]) > 1 THEN 
      'Multiple'
  ELSE 
       ( SELECT [group] FROM test WHERE t.City = city )
  END AS CGroup

FROM 
   test t
GROUP BY 
   City
```

I thought this should be simpler.
Something without a sub query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the `MIN` and `MAX` of the column and then act if they are not identical:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null,[group] char(1) not null,city varchar(20) not null)
insert into @t(ID,[group],city) values
(1,'A','Houston'),
(2,'B','Houston'),
(3,'C','Houston'),
(4,'S','Boston' ),
(5,'R','Detroit')

select city,
   CASE
      WHEN MIN([group]) != MAX([group]) THEN 'Multiple'
      ELSE MAX([group]) END as [group]
from @t
group by city
```

The server should be smart enough to only actually run the `MAX` aggregate once despite it appearing twice in the `select` clause.

Result:

```
city                 group
-------------------- --------
Boston               S
Detroit              R
Houston              Multiple
```

Comment: Wow.. can't believe I missed that. Seems simple now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[@Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17588061/1369235) is perfect. This one is an alternative. If you want to check for more than one (e.g. `COUNT(GROUP) > 2`). Just use `MIN` or `MAX` in `ELSE` like this:

```
SELECT 
  city,
  CASE WHEN COUNT([group]) > 2 
       THEN 'Multiple' 
       ELSE MAX([group]) END  AS Type 
FROM 
  offices
GROUP BY
  city
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d6c4/13)

Answer (score 0):

Use your first query but just use a `MIN` in the `ELSE` part

```
SELECT 
    City, 
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'Multiple'
        ELSE MIN(CityGroup)
    END AS CityGroup
FROM Test
GROUP BY CityGroup
```